# Is a Java socket's PrintWriter thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

So, I have two threads.

Thread one manages the client connections. (There is only one client and one server)
I call it my server thread.

Thread two manages sending messages to the client.  I call it my message processor thread.

Thread one is responsible, among other things sending a heartbeat to the client periodically.

When programming I made an assumption that the sockets weren't thread safe, but the buffers were, and as long as I was using seperate buffers for the server and processor threads I would be fine.

I also made the assumption that the "PrintWriter" was analogous to the socket buffer in Java.

Under these assumptions I wrote this function to send a heartbeat:

```
public void sendHeartBeat(){
        logger.info("Sending a hearbeat!");
        PrintWriter printWriter=null;
        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info(e.toString());
        }
        if(printWriter!=null){
            printWriter.print("HEARTBEAT#");
            printWriter.flush();
        }
    }
```

The other thread, the "processor" one does something similar in that it does:

```
printWriter=new PrintWriter(theServer.getClientSocket().getOutputStream());
```

In this manner I would create a new "buffer" every time I wished to send a heartbeat, and my messages would never get overwritten.

Unfortuneately this does not seem to be the case.  And I get an message coming through the pipe like this:
  dsgdsbHEARTBEAT#sdg

This causes a core dump later.

Here are my questions:

1) Sockets are obviously not thread safe, but are the PrintWriters I get from them thread safe?  Or is it just returning the same PrintWriter?

2) What is analogous to the socket buffer in Java?  How should I think about this problem?

3) How do I make it so that these threads do not write to the same buffer on the socket?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a poor design to have these multiple `PrintWriter`s on the same stream. Really you want at least the object the calls them to be synchronised (or thread confined).

However, assuming for some reason you do want multiple `PrintWriter`s:

First problem: `Writer`s do not use `this` as the lock. `PrintWriter` and `BufferedWriter` by default both use the `Writer` they are constructed with as the lock. This is obviously completely broken. They should be using the `Writer`'s lock, not the `Writer` itself. An easy mistake given that having locking a feature of `Object` removes static type safety. So you'll need to construct a `PrintWriter` with the socket `OutputStream` (or some other common object) as the lock.

Secondly, we have buffering within `PrintWriter`. So come the end of a buffer, half get written and half wait for the next write. To prevent that, either externally lock to combine a `print` and `flush`, or use auto-flushing and add a new line character.

So, it isn't *meaningfully* thread-safe, but you can hack it. Or you can use a better design.

Comment: I took a look at Java SE 1.6.0_31 src for this. 'PrintWriter(Writer out)' ultimately calls 'protected Writer(Object lock)' and there, 'Writer' assigns this 'lock' to its internal 'lock' which is used in 'Writer' for synchronization. So could you pl. explain why you think locking is broken here?

Comment: @shrini1000 `PrintWriter` calls `Writer(Object lock)` with `super(out);`. So `lock` is `out`, instead of `out.lock`. (This is an implementation issue - the specification appears to be missing.)

Comment: This appears to still be the case in Java 8 -- PrintWriter calls super(out) and lock is out instead of out.lock.

Answer (score 5):

You need a way to use the same `PrintWriter` between the threads (`t1.writer == t2.writer`, not just `PrintWriter`s created from the same `OutputStream`). With the same `PrintWriter`, all writing operations are synchronized.

Comment: You are saying that PrintWriters are thread safe, but OutputStreams are not?

Comment: I think Chris saying that PrintWriter is thread-safe, but two on the same stream are not meaningfully thread-safe. Therefore use one.